# Why does main script not work when I place it under all other?

Tags: html

**Version that works**

```
<script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b0ca3cb0f7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

**Version that doesn't work**

```
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b0ca3cb0f7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Does main javascript src needs to be placed at the bottom?
It doesn't work when I put it above all scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work if there are custom functions that you might be calling inside Main.js that are dependent on the other scripts which you are loading.

For eg - There is one script SWIPER JS and you might be calling your custom functions in your main.js i.e. to initialize SWIPER JS SLIDER, so until the dependent script i.e. swiper-bundle.min.js is not loaded the custom function inside main.js won't work.

You can check your console to understand what exact error you get.
Press F12 in your browser.